# How to regroup elements of a cluster?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, associations, gathering, clustering

Given a clustering of unique elements,

```
clustering = {{10, 40, 30}, {200, 500}, {6}, {7}, {8}};
```

How do I group a given subset of them into the same cluster?

eg:

```
input = {10, 40, 500, 6, 200}
output = {{10, 40}, {500, 200}, {6}} (*{{40,10},{200,500},{6}} is ok too, ordering within clusters is not important*)
```

This is my attempt:

I first make a helper function and a mapping of each element to its respective cluster

```
getCluster[cluserting_, m_] :=  SelectFirst[cluserting, MemberQ[#, m] &];
clusterAssociation = Association[# -> getCluster[clustering, #] & /@ Flatten[clustering]]
```

> <|10 -> {10, 40, 30}, 40 -> {10, 40, 30}, 30 -> {10, 40, 30},
> 200 -> {200, 500}, 500 -> {200, 500}, 6 -> {6}, 7 -> {7}, 8 -> {8}|>

This association lets me make use of `GatherBy`

```
GatherBy[input, clusterAssociation]
```

> {{10, 40}, {500, 200}, {6}}

This however feels clunky and not very elegant. Is there a faster / built-in way?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is `Intersection[input, #] & /@ clustering` what you want?

Comment: Very elegant! Yes, but without the `{}`

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher would you please post your comment as an answer? If I use `DeleteCases` to get rid of `{}` your solution is the fastest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose to use

```
Select[ 
  Intersection[input, #] & /@ clustering, 
  Positive@*Length
]
```

The part `Intersection[input, #] & /@ clustering` generates

```
{{10, 40}, {500, 200}, {6}, {}, {}}
```

and `Select[ ..., Positive@*Length ]` gets rid of the empy brackets.
IIRC, this should be a bit faster than using `DeleteCases[ ..., {} ]`. Typically, pattern matching can be a bit slow.

---

What I think should be even more efficient is to first build a lookup table in the form of an `Association` first:

```
lookupTable = AssociationThread[
   Flatten[clustering],
   Flatten[
    MapIndexed[ConstantArray[#2[[1]], Length[#1]] &, clustering]]
   ];
```

One only have to do that once and can reuse it for different queries with different `input`. Such `Associations` allow a very quick lookup of each entry in the list `input`:

```
foundClusters = Lookup[lookupTable, input]
```

> {1, 1, 2, 3, 2}

This means that the first and second elements of `input` lie in `clustering[[1]]`, the third and fifth one lie in the `clustering[[2]]`, and the third one lies in `clustering[[3]]`.

Now -- similar to what the other users did -- you can use `GroupBy` or `GatherBy` to get the finally grouping.

```
GroupBy[Transpose[{foundClusters, input}], First -> Last]
```

> <|1 -> {10, 40}, 2 -> {500, 200}, 3 -> {6}|>

If there is an element `k` in `input` that is not contained in any cluster, then you will also see keys of the form `Missing["KeyAbsent", k]` in the output.

All in all, this is very similar to what user LouisB did. But instead of rules with `ReplaceAll`, we use the more efficient `Lookup` routine.

Comment: Elegant and fast solution!

Answer (score 5):

```
grouper = Function[item, First@Flatten@Position[clustering, item]]
Values@GroupBy[grouper]@input
```

**Edit:**

Or, using `GatherBy` as suggested by kglr's answer:

```
GatherBy[input,grouper]
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it is to drop the unwanted elements from `clustering`.  The unwanted ones are the `Complement` of set `clustering` with respect to subset `input`.  We can use rules that substitute `Nothing` in place of each unwanted element.

```
clustering = {{10, 40, 30}, {200, 500}, {6}, {7}, {8}};

input = {10, 40, 500, 6, 200};

rules = MapIndexed[Rule[#, Nothing] &, Complement[Flatten@clustering, input]];

output = clustering /. rules /. {} -> Nothing

(* {{10, 40}, {200, 500}, {6}} *)
```

Comment: This is very fast too

Answer (score 3):

```
gatherByParent = GatherBy[#, x |-> Cases[#2, {___, x, ___}]] &;

gatherByParent[input, clustering]
```

> ```
> {{10, 40}, {500, 200}, {6}}
> ```